# Deserialising XML produces error Message = "<MyClass xmlns='http://medicareaustralia.gov.au/eclaiming/version 2'> was not expected."

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlserializer

I am having issues with deserializing the following xml. The exception I get reads "http://medicareaustralia.gov.au/eclaiming/version  2'> was not expected."
My lack of exposure to XML and my limited understanding is making this a nightmare for me to get a solution for.

This is what my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<ns1:patienteClaimingResponse xmlns:ns1="http://medicareaustralia.gov.au/eclaiming/version  2">
    <claim medicareAcceptanceType="NAC" assessmentStatus="OK" accountPaidInd="N">
        <voucher voucherId="01">
            <service serviceId="0001" dateOfService="2015  11  17+11:00" assessmentStatus="ERR" chargeAmount="14815" patientContribAmt="4000" mbsItemNum="55036">
            <assessmentExplanation code="9632" /> 
            </service>
            <service serviceId="0002" dateOfService="2015 11 17+11:00" assessmentStatus="OK" chargeAmount="14605" benefitAmount="1" patientContribAmt="4500" scheduleFee="1" mbsItemNum="55032">
            <assessmentExplanation code="0" /> 
            </service>
        </voucher>
    <claimant currentSubnumerate="1" currentMedicareCardNum="6950323991">
        <identity firstName="CELINA" lastName="HOBBS" /> 
    </claimant>
    <patient currentSubnumerate="1" currentMedicareCardNum="6950323991">
        <identity firstName="CELINA" lastName="HOBBS" /> 
    </patient>
    <provider providerNum="2402491W">
        <name>L ARKIE</name> 
    </provider>
    <assessmentError code="0" /> 
    </claim>
</ns1:patienteClaimingResponse>
```

What I'd like to do is deserialise this xml into my classes and my class definitions looks as follows:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<XmlRoot(ElementName:="patienteClaimingResponse", Namespace:="")>
Public Class PatienteClaimingResponse
    <XmlElement("claim")>
    Public Property Claim As Claim
End Class

Public Class Claim
    <XmlAttributeAttribute("medicareAcceptanceType")>
    Public Property MedicareAcceptanceType As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("assessmentStatus")>
    Public Property AssessmentStatus As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("accountPaidInd")>
    Public Property AccountPaidInd As String

    <XmlElement("voucher")>
    Public Property Voucher As Voucher

    <XmlElement("claimant")>
    Public Property Claimant As Claimant

    <XmlElement("patient")>
    Public Property Patient As Patient

    <XmlElement("provider")>
    Public Property Provider As Provider

    <XmlElement("assessmentError")>
    Public Property AssessmentError As AssessmentError

End Class

Public Class Voucher
    <XmlAttributeAttribute("voucherId")>
    Public Property VoucherId As String

    <XmlElement("service")>
    Public Property Services As List(Of Service)
End Class

Public Class Service
    <XmlAttributeAttribute("serviceId")>
    Public Property ServiceId As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("dateOfService")>
    Public Property DateOfService As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("assessmentStatus")>
    Public Property AssessmentStatus As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("chargeAmount")>
    Public Property ChargeAmount As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("benefitAmount")>
    Public Property BenefitAmount As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("patientContribAmt")>
    Public Property PatientContribAmt As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("scheduleFee")>
    Public Property ScheduleFee As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("mbsItemNum")>
    Public Property MbsItemNum As String

    <XmlElement("assessmentExplanation")>
    Public Property assessmentExplanation As AssessmentError

End Class

Public Class Claimant
    <XmlAttributeAttribute("CurrentSubnumerate")>
    Public Property currentSubnumerate As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("CurrentMedicareCardNum")>
    Public Property currentMedicareCardNum As String

    <XmlElement("identity")>
    Public Property Identity As Identity
End Class

Public Class Patient
    <XmlAttributeAttribute("CurrentSubnumerate")>
    Public Property currentSubnumerate As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("CurrentMedicareCardNum")>
    Public Property currentMedicareCardNum As String

    <XmlElement("identity")>
    Public Property Identity As Identity
End Class

Public Class Provider
    <XmlAttributeAttribute("providerNum")>
    Public Property ProviderNum As String

    <XmlElement("name")>
    Public Property Name As String
End Class

Public Class Identity
    <XmlAttributeAttribute("firstName")>
    Public Property FirstName As String

    <XmlAttributeAttribute("lastName")>
    Public Property LastName As String
End Class

Public Class AssessmentError
    <XmlAttributeAttribute("code")>
    Public Property Code As String
End Class
```

Here is my deserialization code

```
Dim ppClaim As New PatienteClaimingResponse
Dim serializer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ppClaim.GetType)
Try
     Dim mystreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Laavanya\EasyClaimRes.xml")
     Dim TargetObject As New PatienteClaimingResponse
     TargetObject = serializer.Deserialize(mystreamReader)
     mystreamReader.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
     Dim s As String = ex.InnerException.ToString 
     'Throws "<patienteClaimingResponse xmlns='http://medicareaustralia.gov.au/eclaiming/version  2'> was not expected."
End Try
```

What i have noticed is that if i remove the alias to the namespace ie the ns1, deserialise does not seem to complain. Should this be the case is there a way to decorate my classes with the alias information as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the root element *iteself* is in the namespace `"http://medicareaustralia.gov.au/eclaiming/version  2"` but all child elements are not in a namespace.  Thus you need to do:

```
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="patienteClaimingResponse", Namespace:="http://medicareaustralia.gov.au/eclaiming/version  2")>
Public Class PatienteClaimingResponse
    <XmlElement("claim", Namespace:="")>
    Public Property Claim As Claim
End Class
```

Working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7sqQHr).